# How to execute/call the sampler in thread1 from thread2 using jmeter?

Tags: selenium, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have created a thread with name thread1 in jmeter with slenium jp@gc-Web Driver Samplers for functional testing. thread1 has many smaplers which can be reused. Now i need to use these samplers of thread1 in any other threads. How can i achieve it in jmeter without copy pasting the same samplers to other tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware of [Module Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller)?

[image: Module Controller]

See [Using JMeter Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) article for detailed explanation if required.

Comment: I used module controller, but to access any sampler inside module controller, the sampler should be always under logic controllers. Is there a way that i can create functions and use the same inside my smaplers?